# Best practice for using Django templates and connect it to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to build a database for my website. There are currently three entries with different attributes in my database. I have not created these entries in order, but I have assigned a 'Chapter number' attribute which indicates the order 1,2,3.

I am now trying to inject this using 'context' and 'render' function in my views. I am using the method 'objects.all()' to add all objects to my context. I have a simple Html file where I am inserting the data from the database by looping over (a simple for loop) these added objects.

Now the output that is being generated (naturally) is that it is following the order in which I created the database. I am not sure how I can have the loop run in such a way that I get these chapters in correct order. Thank you for patiently reading my question. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `order_by` method which is included in Djangos QuerySet API:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/

If you offer some more information of your specific data I might provide you with an example.

For orientation purposes, sorting queried objects by date would work as follows:

```
most_recent = Entry.objects.order_by('-timestamp')
```

You can sort by any field like so:

```
sorted_by_field = Entry.objects.order_by('custom_field')
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much. This solved my problem. I changed context to .order_by() from .all() and it gave me the correct order I was looking for.